# Simple HTML DOM Click Issue

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have a website with an index.php page with AJAX Live Search that connects with a database and returns results. One of theses results is:

```
<div id="searchlinktovideo">Video</div>
```

I also have code in the index.php page to try to do something with the code above, in this case to animate to a page, when the user clicks on it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#searchlinktovideo").click(function () {
    $("#searchpage").animate({
        'left': '-486px'
    }, 200, function () {
        $("#homepage").animate({
            'left': '-486px'
        }, 200, function () {
            $("#videopage").animate({
                'left': '0px'
            }, 200);
        });
    });
});
});
```

It is not working, I think it might be Html DOM related, but I have no idea where to begin to start to tackle the problem.

For now you can find the code at http://www.squbo.com (Click on Search and Type in 'Video' - THE RESULT APPEARS AS HTML, BUT THE JQUERY DOES NOT WORK ON IT))

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser error console or debug console?   And, please post the relevant HTML in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `<div id="searchlinktovideo">Video</div>` is added dynamically (which it sounds like it is), then your problem is probably that you're trying to install the event handler before the item is actually in the page.  This ends up doing nothing because the item can't be found so no event handler is installed.

There are a couple possible solutions.

1. You can use delegated event handling which works with dynamically added elements.
2. You can install your event handler AFTER you add the item to the page.

For delegated event handling, you would use this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#searchlinktovideo", function () {...});
```

Ideally, instead of `$(document)` you would use a selector for a static parent (a parent div that is not added dynamically) closer to `#searchlinktovideo`.

Comment: Yet the delegated click strikes again! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You see jquery looks for `searchlinktovideo` as soon as page is ready but ajax request completes after page is ready, so when it searches for that it finds nothing. You need to use

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
 $("#searchlinktovideo").click(function () {
 ..
 ..
 ..
 });

});
```

Comment: What does this have to do with solving the OP's issue?

Comment: simply calling function after ajax is done would solve this. So when ajax is completed this would be called. That way there would be element searchlintovideo to link to.

Comment: So, you're going to hook up an additional click handler every time any ajax call completes in the page?

Comment: Op didn't say there would be multiple callers.

Comment: OP didn't say that there was only ever one ajax call in the entire lifetime of the page.  This just isn't a safe way to solve the problem.